# How to install Python3 and libraries with Miniconda3 for all users on Windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, miniconda

I want to install Miniconda3 on Windows 10 computers used in a school with a developed network thinking and hierarchy of what admin and users can do.  I also want to add a short number of special python libraries that fit my teaching needs for the students. The problem I face is that the admin privilege makes it possible for me to install Miniconda3 for all users, but then it is actually not enough to install further libraries for all users using conda. But I can very well install further libraries for myself as single users and special environment. Can someone describe what kind of privilege (more than admin) is needed to install further libraries to all users on Windows 10 machine? How can I describe the privileges needed to this installation for IT-people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All installation as admin should be done with PowerShell in mode "run as admin" that you can choose by right click on the PowerShell Icon
and make the choice at start.

Then conda environments can be created and various python-library files can be installed.

In order to make the conda-environment accessible and useful for each individual user you have to adjust the security settings for the folder
ProgramData/Minconda3 where all libraries are stored. The details here
depends on the local security arrangements.

Note ProgramData is usually a hidden folder and you need change a setting to see it.

The problem was solved by the IT responsible at the school.

Here is also today some instruction by Anaconda and I take for granted that these instructions also hold for minconda.

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/multi-user/